# Powershell or C#: Copy files from one location to another using csv data

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a csv with 2 columns. 1st column is the path and filename of the file I want to copy. The second column is the destination path.

I'd like to create a script that parses the csv and copies the files in something like a foreach loop in C#, but I'm thinking Powershell may be the easiest and most efficient way to accomplish this.

Should I load the csv in a C# script, then create a foreach loop that loads the origin and destination and then completes the copy, or would a simple one-liner in Powershell be able to do this quicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powershell will be way easier than to handle this compared to c#. C# will be faster especially if you need to work with threads.

So at the ends, it depends on your requirements. I would recommend powershell for the beginning if you dont need to handle enormous amount of data.

But if youre very familiar with c#, feel free to do it in c# as well

Comment: the csv file is pretty large so I think I might end up going the c# route. thanks

Comment: if the csv is very large the internal powershell will become cery slow. and btw the .net readalllines class as well. in this case use the filestreamer class which is available in powershell and c#

Answer (score 3):

Part of the answer here : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/aa20cabb-3196-472d-9594-aaa0ec10fa03/powershell-read-csv-file-line-by-line-and-only-first-header?forum=winserverpowershell

I would use the powershell if your csv file had headers cause it would be quite easy. But C# if not or if you want some harder process (check if file exists before copying or else)

Comment: gotcha. thanks for the resource. im more familiar with c# and based on the file size of the csv, I think I might go that route anyway.